# How did the Ramayana and Mahabharata wars officially end?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana

How did the main wars of Ramayana and Mahabharata officially end? Meaning no more weapons fired and no more people killed in and due to the war.

*[Who shot the first arrow to start the battle of the Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6639/2995)* prompted me to ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

Ramayana officially ended when Ravana was killed in the battle field, when shot in the beely button, where the Amruta was stored and it dried up due the leakage and hence Rama won as the opponent died, and Vibhishana was made as king of Lanka. Ram along with Sita, Laxmana and Hanuman returned back to captial, Ayodhya.

Mahabharata officially ended after the Gada-yuddha, between Bhima and Duryodhana, Duryodhana was alive for a while and laying down on the battlefield, but there is this after-picture given that Ashwatthama, Krupa and one more fellow Went to see Duryodhana and to take the revenge of Duryodhana's condition, Ashwathama, went to the tents of Pandavas and killed them while they were asleep but few hours ago, Lord Krishna had taken all the pandavas with him for a bath along the river side, to wash all sins after the war. Ashwathama thought he killed all the pandavas but actually those were son's of pandavas.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! You should cite sources for your answer.

Comment: Actually I have read this in Valmiki ramayana, and Mahabharata- story as told by Devdutta Patnaik, this is found in a old puran called as Shrimad Bhagwavatam.

Comment: Apart from this Please check this : http://www.hindunet.org/hindu_history/ancient/ramayan/rama_vartak.html

Comment: http://www.valmikiramayan.net/ (Ramayana) and http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/maha/ ( Mahabharatha). You can find complete online versions from here. So you can quote exact verses from that sites.

Comment: ANIL KUMAR : Please check maximum videos from this https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=devdutt+pattanaik web site and I have hard copy of books for Shrimad Bhagwad gita from ISKCON and also Dongre Maharaj Shrimad Bhagwatam which I usually read and everytime I read it I get something different out of it and some new perspective out of it.